# Problem with XTZ wallet

Tags: smart-contracts, baker, tezbox

I have a question about XTZ Currency. 2 years ago I deligate XTZ to baker using TEZBOX and all these time I haven't checked it. But today I found out that the TEZBOX wallet is not available. I migrated to Temple wallet using a Privat Key, but now I have 0 XTZ on my balance, all my money is on a smart contract, which has been closed for 2 years ago since November 2019. Now There is no way to money back using Temple wallet. Tell me what are the options to get the money back?

Comment: The currency is called "tez", see https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/nomenclature/2376.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the address of the smart contract, check its balance on a block explorer. There is a list [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/#the-community); if you want to interact with a smart contract, [Better Call Dev](https://better-call.dev/) in particular is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the private key from the tz1 address which created the KT1 (used in the past for delegation), then your wallet should be able to transfer the funds out of the KT1 back into your tz1.